# Align Two (2) Images and Objects Inside The Images Using C#

Tags: c#, image-processing, emgucv, aforge, accord.net

I have two images (scanned forms):

The first image is the template image (blank form), and the second image is the image with data in it (form filled out).

I'm trying to align/overlay the image with data to the template image to produce a final image (aligning objects inside the two images to each other).

I'm able to get the quadrilateral corners of both images, transform the quadrilateral corners, and deskew the resulting images (rectangles) but when I overlay the images, I get a double vision final image because the objects inside the two images are not aligned properly.

I've post a question with pictures and link to a video at AForge's forum http://www.aforgenet.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=3013 but have not gotten any response.

I've also looked at Accord.Net's stitching example at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/95453/Automatic-Image-Stitching-with-Accord-NET, but it still doesn't resolve my issue.

Any help is appreciate it.

Comment: If the filled-in form already contains the same content as the template, what are you hoping to achieve by overlaying them? Maybe I misunderstood - some pictures would help.

Answer (score 1):

There is a main reason for this misalignment: The scanning process, document images are very different from normal images.

To explain: During a scan the images are quantized, and this quantization step always results in different sampling of the document, meaning, some black pixels might be white and the other way around (not to the naked eye though).

Add to that, the scanning options might be different, meaning a different dpi, bit depth.

Also the scanners might be different, resulting in a higher mismatch because of the different quantization processes.

Finally, the MAIN problem, is stretching. You might not see, but all scanned documents have a stretching to them, due to feeder, or -yes you guessed it- quantization. This stretching differs from image to another, and is not uniform across a single image. If the image is slightly skewed, the stretching is at an angle, thus dpi is not uniform in different images, nor is the dpi uniform across one image, nor is the variation of the dpi uniform in its direction in any image.

All the above makes it almost impossible to perfectly align one image on top of the other.
Deskewing, and translation via anchoring mechanisms (another topic too long to discuss here), might help, but there are only two ways to try to achieve the above:

1. Apply Morphological Opening after your alignment: Erode followed by dilate. Which creates problems like needing to make the size of the kernel of the above match the size of the image and the dpi, or else you will render some characters unreadable. Also if the content in the image varies in size, you will have to do zoning analysis and blob detection to know what size kernel to perform on what part of the image, then apply general smoothing. (This method is HIGHLY not suggested).
2. Make document analysis of your documents, meaning that you would understand what type of form this is, and that the form has each coordinates and sizes set for each part. After you do your initial alignment, resize the parts of the filled image to match those of the original (requires object isolation via a floodfill algorithm).

In any case, you can see it is not a trivial task, in fact, it is one of the hardest in document image processing and recognition.